# Crashlytics Integration for embedded Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, crashlytics

I am trying to create a third party library that anyone can plugin with minimal setup. For better crash free users, want to integrate crashlytics inside my framework itself.
If main app is using firebase crashlytics as well then this is causing issue.

Is there any way of using two crashlytics just like we can have multiple instances of FirebaseApp?

Comment: Crashlytics doesn't support multiple instances of Firebase app. In a regular app with multiple instances, Crashlytics will use the default. Also, in iOS apps it is not recommended to have multiple crash report frameworks as they can conflict with each other.

Comment: Do you know How does facebook, clevertap etc track crashes then?